# OpenGL calculating Normal of a custom shape

Tags: opengl, glut, glu

i have a shape with the following vertexes and faces:

```
static Vec3f cubeVerts[24] = {
{ -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 },   /* backside */
{ -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 },   
{ -0.3,  4.0, -0.5 },
{ -0.3,  3.0, -0.5 },
{ -0.1,  5.5, -0.5 },
{ -0.1,  4.5, -0.5 },
{  0.1,  5.5, -0.5 },
{  0.1,  4.5, -0.5 },
{  0.3,  4.0, -0.5 },           
{  0.3,  3.0, -0.5 },
{  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 },   
{  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 },   

{ -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 },   /* frontside */
{ -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 },   
{ -0.3,  4.0,  0.5 },
{ -0.3,  3.0,  0.5 },
{ -0.1,  5.5,  0.5 },
{ -0.1,  4.5,  0.5 },
{  0.1,  5.5,  0.5 },
{  0.1,  4.5,  0.5 },
{  0.3,  4.0,  0.5 },           
{  0.3,  3.0,  0.5 },
{  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 },   
{  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 }
};

static GLuint cubeFaces[] = {
0, 1, 3, 2,     /*backfaces*/
2, 3, 5, 4,
4, 5, 7, 6, 
6, 7, 9, 8, 
8, 9, 11, 10,

12, 13, 15, 14, /*frontfaces*/
14, 15, 17, 16,
16, 17, 19, 18,
18, 19, 21, 20,
20, 21, 23, 22,

0, 2, 14, 12,   /*topfaces*/
2, 4, 16, 14,
4, 6, 18, 16, 
6, 8, 20, 18,
8, 10, 22, 20,

1, 3, 15, 13,   /*bottomfaces*/
3, 5, 17, 15,
5, 7, 19, 17,
7, 9, 21, 19,
9, 11, 23, 21,

0, 1, 13, 12,   /*sidefaces*/
10, 11, 23, 22
};
```

and i want to get its normal like this:

```
static Vec3f cubeNorms[] = {
{ 0, 1, 0 },
{ 0, 1, 0 },
{ 0, 1, 0 },
{ 0, 1, 0 }
};
```

Can someone tell me how to calculate its normal and putting it inside an array so i can use all these together like this, i know something is wrong with my normal, because lighting on my shape is not right and i am also not sure if its the right way of setting up the normal, just one example is fine, ive been reading heaps of normal calculations and still can't figure out how to do it.

```
static void drawCube()
{
//vertexes
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, cubeVerts);
//norms
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, cubeNorms);
//faces
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 22 * 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, cubeFaces);
}
```

Comment: With indexed drawing you will need a normal for each vertex - what behaviour do you want when faces share a vertex?

Comment: @Brett Hale, thanks, the shape is a curve with faces connected, i understand that i have to calculate normal for each vertex, but i don't know how to calculate it in my case, can you show me one vertex norm example from my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume your faces are [counter-clockwise front-facing](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2004.html) - I don't know if that's the case - and the quads are, of course, convex and planar.

For a face, take vertices {0, 1, 2}. I don't know the Vec3f specification (or if it's a class or C struct), but we can find the normal for *all* vertices in the quad with:

```
Vec3f va = v0 - v1; // quad vertex 1 -> 0
Vec3f vb = v2 - v1; // quad vertex 1 -> 2
Vec3f norm = cross(vb, va); // cross product.

float norm_len = sqrt(dot(norm, norm));
norm /= norm_len; // divide each component of norm by norm_len.
```

That gives you a [unit normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) for *that face*. If vertices are shared, and you want to give the model the perception of curvature using lighting, you'll have to decide what value of the normal should be 'agreed' upon. Perhaps the best starting point is to simply take an average of the face normals at that vertex - and rescale the result to unit length as required.

Comment: I think you got the order wrong, with ccw faces your code would produce a backward pointing normal. Otherwise correct answer of course.

Comment: @BrettHale Thanks Brett and Christian